# Solving: $x - \sqrt{x+3} - 17 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, factoring

$x - \sqrt{x+3} - 17 = 0$

So i tried this:

$-\sqrt{x+3} = 17 - x$

$\sqrt{x+3} = x - 17$

and then again squaring, but i get quadratic equation which i cannot solve

Comment: Why can you not solve a quadratic equation? [Look up how to do it!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation)

Comment: There is a song to help you remember the solution to quadratic equations. For the quadratic that arises in this particular problem you can actually factor to readily obtain the solutions without punching away in your calculator.

Comment: You can also use $y^2=x+3$ to get to a quadratic more directly and then remember that $y$ should be positive.

Comment: man, do you middle school homework yourself...

Comment: ok @tired i will

Comment: @Cocomos  The main problem with such equation is to exhibit properly the constraint beforehand

Answer (score 2):

It's $$x+3-\sqrt{x+3}-20=0$$ or
$$(\sqrt{x+3}-5)(\sqrt{x+3}+4)=0$$ or
$$\sqrt{x+3}=5$$ or
$$x=22.$$

Comment: where did you get $x + 3 - \sqrt{x + 3} - 20 = 0$

Comment: @Sarvar From your equation. Because $3-20=-17$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Add $\sqrt{x + 3}$ to both sides, then square, and manipulate variables. Then use the quadratic formula.

Comment: Why the down-vote? Anyways, I believe factoring would be easier in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have:

$$x-\sqrt{x+3}-17=0\tag1$$

Subtract $x-17$ from both sides:

$$-\sqrt{x+3}=17-x\tag2$$

Raise both sides to the power of two:

$$x+3=\left(17-x\right)^2=x^2-34x+289\tag3$$

Subtract $x^2-34 x+289$ from both sides:

$$-x^2+35x-286=-\left(x-22\right)\left(x-13\right)=0\tag4$$

Answer (score 0):

THE PROBLEM of Consstraint

your equation make any sens if $x+3\ge 0 $ so we have
$$x - \sqrt{x+3} - 17 = 0\Longleftrightarrow ~~~0\le \sqrt{x+3} = x - 17~~and~~~ x+3\ge 0$$

that is $$ x - 17\ge 0 ~~and~~~ x+3\ge 0 \Longleftrightarrow  x \ge   17~~and~~~ x\ge  -3$$
Wich implies that, $x \ge 17$

**The on the equation is, $x\ge 17$. Now from this we get**

$$(x-17)^2 = x+3  \Longleftrightarrow x^2 -35x +286 = 0$$

$$\Delta = 35^2 - 286 × 4 = 81 =9^2$$
Hence we have $$ x = \frac{35 +9}{2} = 22~~~or~~~x = \frac{35 -9}{2} = 13$$

But dont forget that we have the constraint $x\ge 17$

$$\text{THE ONLY SOLUTION is }~~x = 22$$

Comment: Guy Fsone solution is : 22

Comment: Than nk very much I mess up with sign. Now it is ok .